# Word VBA Progress Bar with Unknown Number of Steps

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that loops through an unknown number of times.  The number of times varies based on a total number of rows in multiple tables in a reference document, and that number of rows will vary across reference documents that may be used.  The relevant snippet of code for the loop is below:

```
For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
    p = p + 1
    Helper.ProgressIndicator_Code (p)
    strPhrase = Split(Trim(oRow.Range.Cells(1).Range.Text), vbCr)(0)
    strRule = Split(Trim(oRow.Cells(2).Range.Text), vbCr)(0)
    If strPhrase <> "" Then
      If Not strStartWord = vbNullString Then
        'Process defined sections
        arrEndWords = Split(strEndWord, "|")
        For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(arrEndWords)
          Set oRng = GetDocRange(strStartWord, arrEndWords(lngIndex))
          If Not oRng Is Nothing Then Exit For
        Next lngIndex
      Else
        'Process whole document
        Set oRng = m_oDocCurrent.Range
      End If
      If Not oRng Is Nothing Then
        Set oRngScope = oRng.Duplicate
        With oRng.Find
          .Text = strPhrase
          Do While .Execute
            If Not oRng.InRange(oRngScope) Then Exit For
            oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
                        If strRule <> "" Then
              Set oComment = m_oDocCurrent.Comments.Add(Range:=oRng, Text:=strUsr & ": " & strRule)
              oComment.Author = UCase("WordCheck")
              oComment.Initial = UCase("WC")
            End If
          Loop
        End With
      End If
    End If
  Next oRow
```

The progress bar is a classic progress bar for which a label field width is updated using the below code based on a value of `p` as updated in the above code:

```
Sub progress(pctCompl As Integer)

  ProgressIndicator.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
  ProgressIndicator.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

  DoEvents

End Sub
```

Here's my problem: The value of p varies based on which reference document is used, so my progress bar is never even approximately accurate with respect to the processing of the VBA macro.  The progress bar doesn't have to be exact, merely close and to indicate that progress is being made and nothing has hung.

I'm not looking for written code, just would be very grateful for suggestions or advice as to approaches for making my progress bar more accurate so that I can learn (e.g., I just ran the macro for three different reference documents - one gave me 25%, one gave 44%, and one gave 82%; none showed even close to 100% when completed).  Essentially I need to divide i by an unknown number to get my percentage, which is clearly impossible, so some function for a close approximation is needed.

**Edit: New code based on @macropod suggestion.**

```
Dim strCheckDoc As String, docRef As Document, projectPath As String, _
  j As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer, oNumRows as Long

j = 1

For i = 0 To UBound(strUsr)
  strCheckDoc = [path to reference document unique to each strUsr]
  Set docRef = Documents.Open(strCheckDoc, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
  
 For k = 1 To docRef.Tables.Count
   oNumRows = oNumRows + docRef.Tables(i).Rows.Count
 Next k
Next i
```

Then the code to update the progress bar is:

```
Dim pctCompl As Single

pctCompl = Round((p / oNumRows) * 100)
ProgressIndicator.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
ProgressIndicator.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

DoEvents
```

The progress bar now gets to 64% when complete (i.e., it should be at 100%).  I'm also working on a way to make `oNumRows` only count a row if the row has content in the first column.

Comment: If you don't know then you say what you've done.

Comment: So get a count of the rows from oTbl.Rows.Count, then calculate pctCompl for p as a percentage of that.

Comment: @macropod Ok, I think you've gotme on the right track here.  The problem I'm running into is that blank rows in the tables are also being counted, which I believe is throwing things off.  For `oNumRows` of 28 (only 14 of which contain data), my progress bar is only getting to 64% when everything is completed.  I've updated the OP code to reflect the changes based on your suggestion.

Comment: Since you have multiple tables, you'll need to either re-set oNumRows to oTbl.Rows.Count and p = 0 for each table (resulting in 0-100% being repeated for however many tables there are), or aggregate the row count for all of them (e.g., via a loop) to get the overall oNumRows value, then loop through all the table a second time for the actual processing (without resetting p between tables).

Comment: Or you could ignore the number of rows and simply advance the progress bar after each table has been processed.

Comment: I notice the doEvents.  That may cause user interface events to be processed during your long running task. Running tasks as background tasks overcome that albeit at the expense of more complicated code.

Comment: @macropod I believe `oNumRows` is being aggregated in the current code in the nested For loop.  The value of `oNumRows` is accurate across the full set of documents and tables if empty rows are counted.